# How do I setup/install Geolite2 for Geoip

Tags: php, installation, geoip, geolite2

I'd like to setup some basic geoip location on my website. I'd like to detect the country the user is coming from and then run some php script to direct them to a specific location. To do this I want to use Geolite2 from Maxmind.

However all of the advice I've come across is pre Jan 2019 which is no longer relevant for the updated product set that Maxmind now produces.
I can't quite get my head around what I need to download and install.

I'd appreciate any advice or help you could give.

Many thanks.

Comment: The [GeoIP2 PHP API](https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php) installation guide is not working for you?

Comment: Thank you. Not really, I'm a bit out of my depth with what's being suggested. The previous version required 3 files and a database to be download, which I could manage, but I don't understand the terminology in this article. How do I run the commands in the root directory? I'm sorry I realize my experience is lacking, but it looks like i need to use a cmd line to do the downloads, and I don't know how!

Comment: I've managed to get it all working. The documentation is confusing to say the least if you've not got a huge amount of experience with installing software through a Control Panel on a server. My issues were due to not have access on the control panel that would have made it easier for me to work out the install process.I resolved this by passing everything over to my hosting companies support and getting them to do it for me. This worked, but I feel let down that I couldn't do it myself and learn from it. Hey ho!